# Instance, Session and Concurrency for duplex service

Tags: wcf

I have a requirement where a service should be sending a message to client every second. There  can be only one client to the service.

I have a created a duplex service and now confused on instance, concurrency and session for the service.

1. Is session always required for a duplex service? SessionMode.Required
2. Does the InstanceContextMode should always be PerSession. InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession?
3. What should be the ConcurrencyMode?
4. How can I prevent additional client connection to the service. Should the callback reference in teh client be static and check for null reference when client request is initially received.
5. I’ll be implementing a heartbeat operation to check the availablity of the service. Should this be a one-way or request reply call and would this call be in same session?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

May be I'm late for a few month... If you have only one client and will not have more clients in future, you can use simplest settings: InstanceContextMode.Singleton, SessionMode.NotAllowed.

About ConcurrencyMode you can read in this tutorial: http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/Concurrency-Management/Service-Concurrency-Mode/